# Laravel Relational Data Inserting While We Do not Have Ids [Multiples Relational Inside]

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to insert a data in Laravel 10. Using int foreign key [example: 2]. However the value of the input is its name not the id [example: facebook.com].

Simuation:

1: google.com
2: facebook.com

I cannot insert based on its id since this is a scraper program which run in python, I cannot call every API only to get the source ID. That is why we return the value.

Model

```
   public function propertySource(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PropertySource::class);
    }

    public function propertyNetworkPost(): HasMany{
        return $this->hasMany(PropertyNetworkPost::class);
    }
```

Controller

```
public function storeUrl(Request $request){
        if(!$request->ad_urls){
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>'failed',
                'notification'=>__('Tidak ada input')
            ]);
        }

        ///Decoding nesting json
        $ad_urls = $request->ad_urls ?? [];
        if(!is_array($ad_urls)){
            $ad_urls = json_decode($request->ad_urls,true);
        }

        ///Creating array for mass insert
        $input = [];
        foreach($ad_urls as $item){
            $input [] = [
                'country' => $request->country,
                'source_id' => $request->source, => HERE IS THE PROBLEM, NEED TO RETRIEVE THE ID WHILE WE HAVE THE NAME
                'ad_url' => $item,
            ];
        }

        try{
            ///Ignore when duplicates and get affected rows
            $rows = PropertyVault::insertOrIgnore($input);
            if(empty($rows)){
                throw new PropertyException(message: 'no url to insert');
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw new PropertyException(message: $e->getMessage());
        }
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => __("Inserting {$rows} urls"),
        ]);
    }
```

I can easily gather the id. However, need to make it working in laravel. I read laravel documentation and also tried this code but seems that it insert to the parent

```
    $propertySource = PropertySource::where('name',$request->source)->first();

    $status = $propertySource->propertyVault()->create([
        'country' => 'ID',
        'source_id' => 1,
        'ad_url' => 'https://google'.rand(0,1999).'.com',
    ]);
```

Comment: $request->source always is one record? And you want to take the ID from the PropertySource table with the name? Right?

Comment: @Aro Sure, I want to achieve that. However, everything should come from Model Relations as Laravel documentation stated